# Django templates for one row 4 objects

Tags: html, css, django, templates, for-loop

I send to my django template page.html 12 objects with different heights. I want display them per one .row 4 object. In python terminal I can do this. I need alternative for template

```
if a % b == 0:
    print('</div> <div class="row" ')
else:
    print('<div class="item">')
```

I couldn't use

```
forloop.counter
```

result must be like this

```
a b d f
b f d k
d k a b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in `divisibleby` templatetag like this:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    {% if forloop.first or forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}
        <div class="row" >
    {% endif %}

    <span>{{ obj }}</span>

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 or forloop.last %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Take note that we use `forloop.counter0` in the first condition. Note the `0` in the end.

Comment: Thank you!  It's alright!  How did you get my text ?! you are genius!))

Comment: Glad it helped. I just analyzed the result you mentioned. :D